# Insertion in database sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite

If I have two tables in a database

```
table1
id_app | description
```

id_app is primary key of table1

```
table2
id_person | name | id_app
```

(id_person, id_app) is primary key of table2

if I execute this:

```
this.stat = conn.createStatement();
String sql = "INSERT INTO `table2` (id_person,name,aplication) VALUES (\""+id_person+"\", \""+name+"\", \""+aplication+"\")";
stat.executeUpdate(sql);
```

I can insert a person with an application thats not define in the table1, is this posible? Or I define something wrong in my database?
I can restrict this in my java program but I wanted to know if there is a way to restrict this from the database?

my database definition looks something like this

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id_app`      TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `description` TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   PRIMARY KEY(`id_app`)
);

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
 `id_person`   TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 `aplication`  TEXT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(`aplication`) REFERENCES `table1`(`id_app`),
  PRIMARY KEY(`id_person`,`aplication`)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite doesn't enforce foreign keys by default, as mentioned in this [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys):

> As of SQLite version 3.6.19, the default setting for foreign key enforcement is OFF. However, that might change in a future release of SQLite. The default setting for foreign key enforcement can be specified at compile-time using the SQLITE_DEFAULT_FOREIGN_KEYS preprocessor macro. To minimize future problems, applications should set the foreign key enforcement flag as required by the application and not depend on the default setting.

You'll need to execute the statement `PRAGMA foreign_keys=1;` if you want to enable foreign key enforcement. I believe you need to do this for each new `Connection` but I may be mistaken. The `1` can be substituted with `true`, `yes`, or `on`.

You can also configure the `Connection` when you open it using [`DriverManager.getConnection(String, Properties)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection(java.lang.String,java.util.Properties)) by using the `Properties` argument. You don't mention it in your question, but since this is Java and you are using SQLite I'm assuming you are using the driver provided by [xerial/sqlite-jdbc](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc). This library provides the [`SQLiteConfig`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.23.1/org/sqlite/SQLiteConfig.html) class which has the following convenience method: [`enforceForeignKeys(boolean)`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.23.1/org/sqlite/SQLiteConfig.html#enforceForeignKeys-boolean-).

You can convert a `SQLiteConfig` instance to `Properties` with [`SQLiteConfig.toProperties()`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.23.1/org/sqlite/SQLiteConfig.html#toProperties--).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a [FOREIGN KEY](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) restriction from `table2` to `table1`.  A foreign key restriction tells the database to ensure that a value exists in `table1` before allowing a value in that column of `table2`.

## EDIT after question modified

Two thoughts come to mind:

1. Have you *enabled* FOREIGN KEY support?

   In some setups of SQLite, the foreign key functionality is either not compiled in, or compiled in but disabled by default.  For the latter cases, you might have to [enable it with a PRAGMA directive](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable).
2. I don't generally set TEXT columns as PRIMARY KEYs.  You may have more success if you can refactor the `id_app` columns to be of INTEGER type.

Comment: I edit my question because I am using foreign keys, that´s way I thing it´s strange that work this way

Comment: May I assume that `...REFERENCES \`Aplication\`...` should be `...REFERENCES \`table1\`...` in the context of the question?

Comment: yes, sorry. I edit it

Answer (score 0):

You may use foreign keys in the DB structure:

https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.